# Insert comma separated values into MySQL table field

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, insert

I've a text file that contains many megabytes of comma separated values (about 10 Mb): I must insert these values in a mysql db. Any value must be stored in a different row of a specific field of a table. Any suggestion is appreciated (I can eventually use PHP if needed).

Comment: If you have access to office, open the CSV in Excel, Save in Open Document Format, and import it into phpmyadmin directly, It will even make the table for you

Comment: The table is in a remote db and has many different fields (I can't substitute their content). Moreover, I red there can be issues with loading so much rows at a time.

Answer (score 1):

For this tasks I use tools such us [Talend](http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/menu.php). You can do all kind of imports from CSV, files excel, etc, up to 450 connectors. it's open source and there is also a paid version with more features. It's java but you don't need to code in java unless you want to do something the application is not capable of doing.
You may need to invest 3/4 hours doing the tutorias but it's worth the hassle.

Good luck

Comment: That's overkill, he can do his task in 30 lines of code

Comment: @message: the file is more than 6000 pages in OpenOffice. I though I could split the pages, then use PHP, but I was wondering if there's a less "primitive" way to do it

Comment: talend it's more flexible, once you learn it you can do this in 3 minutes with basically all databases and most commonly used file formats

Answer (score 0):

Just use search bar, there is a lot of samples at stackoveflow. Main phases:

1. [Parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) CSV file
2. Initiate database connection through [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)
3. Run for/foreach loop to populate database

Comment: This is exacly what I wanted to do, but I thought there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a php script in which you can:

1. Use explode method to get all the entries in an array format
2. Then run a for/foreach loop over that array to add elements to database

Comment: This is what I wanted to do when I decided to ask if there was any better way than having PHP open a 10 Mb text file, split values by commas and query the db...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a table with same numbers of column CSV file have.
Than you can run this query into mysql to load the CSV file data into created table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: The csv file only stores data for ONE column: I must insert this data in an existing table

Comment: Once imported to a temp table you can then insert to your existing table using queries on this temp table.